# Plotting large sf dataframe

Tags: r, gis, large-data, r-sf, tmap

I need to work with a 10minutes (1/12th degree) global grid of all land areas. The grid is generated in R using package (sf). The grid is to be limited to land areas of the world. Grid ID is needed for further down-stream analysis. Code generating the grid is below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
sf_use_s2(F)

birds <- st_read('BOTW_breeding_valid_union.gpkg') ## This is just an examplary shapefile I use to set a bbox.
bbox <- st_bbox(birds)
bbox[1] <- -180
bbox[2] <- -90
bbox[3] <- 180
bbox[4] <- 90

bbox <- bbox %>% st_as_sfc
grid <- st_make_grid(bbox, cellsize = 1/12) %>% st_as_sf() %>% mutate(grid_ID = row_number())

land <- st_read('ne_10m_land.shp')

land_grids <- st_intersects(grid, land) %>% as.data.frame() %>% rename(grid_ID = row.id)

grid <- grid %>% left_join(land_grids, by = "grid_ID") %>%  filter(col.id == "1")  %>% select(grid_ID) %>%
 st_write('global_10m_grid.gpkg')
```

Now I need to plot it to inspect it and for further data mapping (the grids will have values). I use package tmap:

```
grid <- st_read('global_10m_grid.gpkg')
bitmap('test_grid.png')
tm_shape(grid) + tm_fill(col = 'red')
dev.off()
```

However, I am struggling due to the size either on a personal machine (takes incredibly long time to load [or so I hope as it hasn't loaded in principle just yet]) or on a cluster with interactive shell (dev.off produced an empty file).

Is there a way to plot this more efficiently?

Comment: have you tried with `tmap_mode("view")`?

Comment: Trying it right now, but has been running for about 15 minutes and still no plot generated in RStudio.

Comment: No luck! Still rather ineffective and can't get a global plot.

Comment: Do you require grid as vector polygons? Wouldn't a raster object be sufficient in this case? You can rasterize any data to raster cells and plot it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rasterising was indeed the solution. Maintaining the resolution of the vector in raster results in files just under 11 mb, perfectly openable in a normal RStudio setting on my Desktop.

For future references, the code looks like this:

```
g <- st_read('yourfile.gpkg')

library(stars)

g %>% left_join(df, by = 'grp') %>% select(value) %>% st_rasterize(n = 2773927) %>% write_stars('filename.tif')
```